# Reindexing without SSH

Tags: magento2

I'm developing a magento store on a server which i don't have access to SSH right now. Can we possibly reindex without SSH?

http://screencast.com/t/v3pb8E8Ho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can using cron. You can also set your indexing mode for index on schedule to avoid delays every time you save a product, for example.

- [Set up cron](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron)
- In the Admin, go to **System** > Tools > **Index Management** to set the indexing mode

Comment: yes, ik that is one way of doing that i've tried it without any success. What if some indexes are already invalidated will this approach take care of as well?

Comment: Yes. Make sure cron is running as the correct user, NOT the web server user.

Comment: well, i still haven't figured out the right way to do this so finally ended up doing it vai SSH. I know this is possible with approach you are suggesting, so i will accept your answer for other visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can Re-Index using Admin Panel. Here Re-Index can be done in two modes.

- Update on Save
- Update on Schedule

**To do so-**

Log in to the Magento Admin.

Go to System and under Tools, click Index Management.

Select the checkbox next to each type of indexer to change.

Select the indexing mode from the Actions dropdown.

Click Submit.

[image]